# Stubbing request across entire project

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, sinon, proxyquire

I'm writing tests for a small REST library that implements OAuth's refresh grant on top of the [request](https://github.com/request/request) library. As part of it's functionality, it's providing a retry function that has something like this in `rest.js`:

```
const auth = require('./auth');
const request = require('request');

function retry(headers, responseHandler) {
  headers.auth.bearer = auth.getToken();
  request(headers, function(err, resp) {
    if (resp.error && resp.error == 'invalid_token') {
      return auth.renew(function(e, r) { retry(headers, responseHandler); });
    }
    // handle happy case
  });
});
```

What `auth.renew` does is posting to the token provider with the information in `headers` and internally known refresh token. The important bit is that it does this by using `request.post`, passing the recursive event handler down to the request library.

Naturally, when I test this, I don't want outgoing HTTP calls. So I use sinon to stub them out:

```
const requestStub = sinon.stub(),
    rest = proxyquire('./rest', { 'request': requestStub }),
    authFail = { error: 'invalid_token' },
    authSuccess = { token: '123' };

describe('#retry', () => {
  it('calls retry twice on failed auth', () => {
    requestStub.yields(null, authFail);
    requestStub.post = sinon.stub().yields(null, authSuccess);

    retry({}, () => {});
    sinon.assert.calledTwice(requestStub);
  });
});
```

The problem is that `auth.renew` happily goes on to `require('request')` on it's own and thus never seeing my stub. So I guess my **question** is:
How do I make `auth` use my stubbed `request` instead of its own?

I know sinon can [stub XHR](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/fake-xhr-and-server/), but that seems like a lot of low-level effort for what I want.

Comment: So I found two things: `@global` on a proxyquire will replace that module transitively. But the readme warns explicitly against using it. My issue _seems_ to be with how proxyquire doesn't interfere with the module content for `auth.js` and only modifies `rest`'s view of auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with was to replace the entire `auth.renew` method, so the thing looks like this:

```
const requestStub = sinon.stub(),
    rest = proxyquire('./rest', { 'request': requestStub, 
      './auth': { 
        renew: function(callback) {
          requestStub.yields(null, authSuccess);
          callback();
        }
    }),
    authFail = { error: 'invalid_token' },
    authSuccess = { token: '123' };

describe('#retry', () => {
  it('calls retry twice on failed auth', () => {
    requestStub.yields(null, authFail);

    retry({}, () => {});
    sinon.assert.calledTwice(requestStub);
  });
});
```